# Gluon build as single Jar

Tags: executable-jar, javafxports, gluon, gluon-desktop

I'd like to build my Gluon Project as a SINGLE executable jar file.

Currently there is a startup script included with a bin folder and so on.

Is it possible to build a single jar? Or can I include an own gradle task that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had to build the jar with javapackager I used this plugin: [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin)

I am relatively new to Gradle so adding the dependencies is just a temporary solution but it works

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.4.1'
    }
}

jfx {
    verbose = true
    mainClass = "package.path.to.main.class.MainClass"
    jfxAppOutputDir = "build/jfx/app" //configurable
    jfxMainAppJarName = "ProjectName.jar"
    deployDir = "src/main/deploy" //for signing

    //many more options, go to link to learn about them
}


jfxJar.doFirst {
    //TODO add all desktop dependencies
    println("adding desktop dependency")
    project.dependencies.add("runtime", "com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:2.1.0")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current tasks like `installApp` or `distZip` will not bundle the jars in one.

If you want to create a 'fat-jar', you can add this [plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to your build.gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

And then run `gradlew shadowJar`. It will create under libs an executable jar.

Note: if you are using `desktopCompile` or `desktopRuntime` dependencies, those won't be included so you need to change those to `compile` or `runtime`.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I fixed it myself.  
I had Problems building it like a normal jar because of Javafx.  
But now works :D